# Creating new directories upon account registration using mkdir

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm having difficulties having my script automatically create new directories upon account registration.

### **My code:**

```
$bloguser=$_POST['bloguser'];
$root = "/accounts/";
if(!is_dir($root.$bloguser, 0777))
    mkdir($root.$bloguser, 0777);
if(!is_dir($root.$bloguser."/images", 0777))
    mkdir($root.$bloguser."/images", 0777);
if(!is_dir($root.$bloguser."/images/avatar", 0777))
    mkdir($root.$bloguser."/images/avatar", 0777);
```

### **The problem:**

The account registers just fine. However, the is_dir and mkdir are giving me errors:

Warning: Wrong parameter count for is_dir() in...

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Unable to access /accounts/TestAccount in...

Warning: Wrong parameter count for is_dir() in...

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Unable to access /accounts/TestAccount/images in...

Well, you get the idea.

### **Things I've tried/Things to know:**

- I gave the `accounts` folder in the root those 0777 writing rights, just to make sure the writing rights aren't the problem;
- I've tried toying around with the double quotes, such as putting them
  around the variables;
- I also tried to leave the 0777 stuff out of the checks whether the directory exists: if(!is_dir----

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: is_dir only accepts a string (the dirname)

Comment: Try to read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: You could also use mkdir recursivly: mkdir($path, 0755, true);

Comment: Ah, so the problem would most likely be solved if I do "$root = "/accounts/" . $bloguser;" and then change all the "$root.$bloguser" to "$root"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way. [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) has `recursive` option:

```
mkdir($root.$bloguser."/images/avatar", 0777, true);
```

The first thing always to do when programming PHP, is reading the documentation. There is a lot in there and the community comments often address common problems.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll try this out. I actually tried reading the documentation before getting on here, but I couldn't access PHP.net for whatever reason... it started working again just now.

Comment: I think it SHOULD work, but I'm getting error Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. Probably because I'm using the oh-so great free zymic hosting. I can't turn SAFE MODE off in php.ini or anything of the sort. I don't presume there's a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the is_dir manual https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-dir.php

```
bool is_dir ( string $filename )
```

you can check if you have write permissions with

```
bool is_writable ( string $filename )
```

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-writable.php